# Mac os x 10.5.8 macintosh and windows xp installed with Boot Camp

Tags: macos, mac, boot-camp

Could I erase the Macintosh because i want to work only with Windows, or is there another way to have only windows on my mac?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can erase the drive and install Windows on it. Or Linux.

Or you could run Windows in Boot Camp, or in Fusion, or Parallels, or Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP works on a Mac because of the BootCamp software: it emulates a BIOS from the hardware EFI, so Windows can boot. So without BootCamp, you cannot run Windows XP on a Mac.

One solution is install a very minimal Mac system (without translations or printer drivers): it could fit into less than 20Gb. Then use BootCamp as usual.

Comment: I've seen XP running on Apple hardware sans Boot Camp.. was that a fluke?

Comment: Didn't kwnow about it. Maybe it is possible after running BootCamp once.